# How to get the node.js package path(wherever installed) along with its name and version

Tags: node.js, npm

I know with this(npm -g ls --json) command we will get package name and version.
I also need complete path where the package is installed globally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `--long` option which will show extended information including paths.

```
npm ls -g --json --long
```

Comment: Thanks Gergo, exactly as it is needed. :)